# Proving $|d(x,z)-d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$ and $|d(x,y)-d(a,b)| \leq d(x,a) +d(y,b)$ in a metric space $(X,d)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, I want to prove the following inequalities:

$$\tag{1}|d(x,z)-d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y),$$

and

$$\tag{2}|d(x,y)-d(a,b)| \leq d(x,a) +d(y,b).$$

I understand $(1)$ as one side of the triangle is always larger than the difference of the lenghts from the remaining two sides of the triangle. For $(1)$, I have that since we are in a metric space $0 \leq d(x,y) \leq d (x,z) +d (z,y)$. Also $|d(x,z) -d(y,z)|=|d(x,z) - d(z,y)|$ since $d(z,y)= d(y,z)$.  But after trying to figure out how I prove the mentioned inequality with the obsevations I made, I cant still solve the inequality. For $(2)$ Im

Comment: What assumptions are you making about $d$?

Comment: $d$ is a metric space. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: The triangle inequality is already a metric space axiom, so you can prove the first rather easily from this by considering the cases $d(x,z) \geq d(y,z)$ and $d(x,z) < d(y,z).$

Comment: I sincerely doubt it; perhaps you meant that it is a **metric** or a distance function (not a "metric space"). The question stands: what is your definition of "metric"? There are multiple ways of defining a distance, in which some things are assumed and other things are proven. We need to know your *exact* definitio in order ot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove the first inequality, notice that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)\\\\
d(y,z) \leq d(y,x) + d(x,z)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
d(x,z) - d(y,z) \leq d(x,y)\\\\
d(y,z) - d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

whence we conclude the desired result holds (why?).

With the purpose to prove the second inequality, observe that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
d(x,y) \leq d(x,a) + d(a,b) + d(y,b)\\\\
d(a,b) \leq d(a,x) + d(x,y) + d(y,b)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
d(x,y) - d(a,b) \leq d(x,a) + d(y,b)\\\\
d(a,b) - d(x,y) \leq d(x,a) + d(y,b)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

whence we conclude the desired result holds (why?).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @Sok De nada :-)

Answer (score 1):

A standard trick is to add 0 and use the triangle inequality.
$|d(x,y)-d(a,b)| = |d(x,y)-d(a,y) + d(a,y) - d(a,b)| \leq  |d(x,y)-d(a,y)| + |d(a,y) - d(a,b)| \leq d(x,a) + d(y,b)$

Comment: Danke schön Robin!